# Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am already passing the subnetIds as list but still getting the error:

```
  VpcEndpointSubnetIds:
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    Description: Select the subnet to associate with the VPC endpoint
    Default: 'subnet-039c1ac2c0925fe94,subnet-0e9267fe210b042da'

  VPCEndpointGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        ServiceName: !Ref dynamoDbEndPointServiceName
        VpcEndpointType: Gateway
        PrivateDnsEnabled: true
        SubnetIds:
          -
            !Ref VpcEndpointSubnetIds
        SecurityGroupIds:
          -
            !Ref cacheSecurityGroup
```

Not sure what is causing the error? Did I miss something?

**Update:**
After fixing the spacing issue, now I get error:

```
Value of property {/SubnetIds/0} does not match type {String}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a template formatting issue.

Also the `SubnetIds` property is only supported by **Interface** and **Gateway Load Balancer** VPC endpoint types. For the **Gateway** type you can not use this property, so you need to remove it:

```
  VPCEndpointGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
        ServiceName: !Ref dynamoDbEndPointServiceName
        VpcEndpointType: Gateway
        PrivateDnsEnabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref cacheSecurityGroup
```

For more information check the [AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html#aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint-properties) doc

Comment: The issue was joining the `,` but I get other error: `Subnet IDs are only supported for Interface and GatewayLoadBalancer type VPC Endpoints. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: cd121a48-cfd4-499a-9742- 38d501c4ef96;`